# MyUser login in Django 1.5. Again

Tags: django, forms, authentication, model

I try to login users from MyUser model in django 1.5. I use e-mail as login, see model:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        db_index=True,
    )
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    second_name=models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    post=models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['last_name','first_name','second_name','post',]

    def get_full_name(self):
       return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
       return self.email

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
       return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
       return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

And I added LoginForm:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
username = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
password =forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False),max_length=100)
```

view:

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/home.html")# Redirect to a success page.
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/account/invalid/")# Return a 'disabled account' error message
    form=LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'enter.html', {'login_form': LoginForm})
```

template:

```
{% if form.errors %}
<p>Something is wrong</p>
{% endif %}

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="email">Login:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email"/>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="username">

    <input type="submit" value="login" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{next|escape}}" />

</form>
```

urls:

```
(r'^login/$', login_view),
```

**Problem:**  It works for users from default User model (username, password), but this form "doesn't know" users from MyUser model (email, password), it redirect them to `/account/invalid` page. 
What am I doing wrong?
Thx!

Comment: you need to map ur `Myuser` model to `auth User` model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to indicate your custom user model in settings:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
```

Also, you have to provide custom UserManager, from [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/):

> You should also define a custom manager for your User model. If your
>   User model defines username and email fields the same as Django’s
>   default User, you can just install Django’s UserManager; however, if
>   your User model defines different fields, you will need to define a
>   custom manager that extends BaseUserManager providing two additional
>   methods: